# HTML Element COL, color & width CSS properties not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

When I am trying to apply different CSS properties on col tags in HTML, to have different styling to one Table Column, its not working. Only "background-color" is working. color, width, font-style CSS properties not working on columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#col-1{

    background-color: blue;
    color: white;   
    width: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col id="col-1">
    <col id="col-2">
    <col id="col-3">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5869207</td>
    <td>My first CSS</td>
    <td>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use class to add css and class to respective th and td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate CSS class with required styling and apply it to either `<tr>` or `<td>` based on your requirement.

Comment: Yeah we can do by applying class to every td element & adding CSS thereafter. But I am looking for application/use of col & cogroup. Why applying these Styling properties on col not working ?  col & colgroup  is made for this right i.e to add different styling to individual columns  right??

Comment: you can apply only background,border and width to col tag

Comment: ok. thanks for support  Vasanthi GV. Any links with some more explanation would be appreciable .

Answer (score 5):

Only `border`, `background`, `width` and `visibility` are applied to `<col>` and `<column-group>` elements https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns

To change the color in the first column you'll need a couple of rules that target the first child of each row:

```
tr>th:first-child {
  color: white;
}
tr>td:first-child {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of other methods like - applying class to every td element & adding CSS thereafter or as you explained above. But I am looking for application/use of col & cogroup. Why applying these Styling properties on col not working ?  col & colgroup  is made for this right i.e to add different styling to individual columns  right?? even width & height properties now working. As you may check my code above. width applied to respective Id not working..

Comment: As I mentioned only those 4 properties apply, it is because of the W3 specification that I also mentioned above: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns

Comment: The styling limitations of `<col>` represent a missed opportunity. Today I tried the `text-align` property, only to discover that *it too* does not work on <col>. Well I'm not going to spend time styling each cell all the way down the column. The text can just stay ugly and hard to read. Pass along the pain of CSS to the users, lol. I'm not caving in to *the Man*. Are you listening, W3?!